# What is the equivalent of Java Scanner in Kotlin?

Tags: java, input, kotlin, java.util.scanner

What is the equivalent of Java `Scanner` in Kotlin?

I have used `readLine()` but I'd like to know whether it's type safe or not?

Comment: What do you mean by 'type safe'? `readLine()` is supposed to return a `String` or `null` if it reached the end of input. I see no possibility to violate type safety since no types other than `String?` are involved.

Comment: You can still use `Scanner` in Kotlin if you want to read primitive types directly without handling parsing/casting, since it is fully compatible with Java

Comment: Using Scanner we can read the values as int, String etc. But `readLine()` always  return a String. Instead of type cast the value every time, i wish to read the value as nextInt() or nextString().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)

val n = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()
```

Since "in" is a [Kotlin keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html)

Answer (score 8):

**Kotlin** reuses many existing Java libraries and it's perfectly fine to do so with `Scanner`. Otherwise, [`readLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) simply uses `System.in` as you can see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.20/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L181). This might be a simple alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks @s1m0nw1 . I have reused the `Scanner` in my app. Works fine.